# Поддержка python старых версий

Tags: python, tkinter, nuitka

Подскажите, будет ли работать код написанный на python 3.9 и запакованный в exe при помощи nuitka или PyInstaller вместе с python39.dll и пр. на машине с python 2.6? (скорее всего срарая OS Vista/Vin7/Win8.1)

Comment: Не будет. Если вам надо 2.6 — пишите сразу на 2.6, и собирайте pyinstaller'ом тоже в 2.6

Comment: andreymal, а нафига тогда вообще nuitka или PyInstaller существуют? я предполагал для того чтобы можно было пользоваться если у тебя вообще нет питона на ПК, для передачи на другие ПК.... разве это не так?

Comment: Именно для того и существуют, да. Только вот они не являются магическими инструментами, которые чудесным образом добавят поддержку Vista для питона 3.9. Если вам нужна Vista — используйте хотя бы 3.8 — это последняя версия, которая способна работать Vista/7

Comment: В общем это связано с поддержкой питона с самой OS...  к примеру: если питон 3.9 можно было бы запустить на vista, то все бы сработало, верно? какие OS поддерживает python 3.9 ?

Comment: Возможно сработало бы. О требованиях питона к системе читайте в документации https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Работоспособность собранного в exe файла не зависит от установленных на машине интерпретаторов Python, но зависит от того, поддерживается ли система интерпретатором, с помощью которого программа была упакована в exe.

Comment: Вообще, Python 3.4 поддерживает старые версии Windows, начиная с Windows XP. Python 3.5-3.6 по идее должны работать на Vista, точно работают на Win 7. Python 2.7 по идее должен работать также начиная с Win XP (не гарантирую), и точно работает на Win 7. Нет смысла использовать такую древность, как Python 2.6.